# How do I copy objects from a ArrayList and order them by int size in a HashMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I need to make a leaderboard, the place on it depends on the quantity of points a Client has.

This is the Client,

```
public Client(String username, String password, String phoneNumber, String nickname, Integer score) {

        super(username, password);

        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

        this.nickname = nickname;

        this.score = score;

}
```

The Clients are stored in a Clients ArrayList, and for the leaderboard only the "nickname" and the "score" need to be shown ordering them from bigger score to smaller. I was recommended to use HashMap but as I am new to java I have never tried it before.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for the help :D 
and please say anything you must beacause I am really new to this and dont have much idea of how things work, any tip is well recived :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already using `ArrayList` and you need to order that `list` using custom logic, you need to provide a `Comparator` to compare between `Clients`:

Here is an example of how to do it:

// define a comparator class.

```
class SortbyScore implements Comparator<Client> 
{ 
    // Used for sorting in descending order(bigger to smaller) of  score
    public int compare(Client a, Client b) 
    { 
        return b.score - a.score; 
        // if you want ascending order (smaller to bigger)
        // return a.score - b.score; 
    } 
}


....
// in your main method.. 
List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<>();
...
/// insert data into clientList.

// sort client list;
Collections.sort(clientList , new SortbyScore());

// now client list will contain the sorted data.
System.out.println("Sorted: " clientList);
// Better use for-loop and print each element.
```

Not sure why you are suggested to use HashMap.

Check this links for more: [How to Sort in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/)